# Terraform - Error: Unsupported attribute, This object does not have an attribute named "name"

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm kind of new to Terraform and I am trying to construct Azure Private DNS zones within an Azure subscription.

In Terraform, I am trying to create that resource utilizing a map object within a module. Here is the code that I have:

**Root Module**

```
dns_zone = {
    "private.vaultcore.azure.net" = {
      registration_enabled = false
      vnet_link_name       = join("-", [data.azurerm_key_vault.existing-keyvault.name, "link"])
      vnet_id              = data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing-vnet.id
      a_record = [
        {
          name         = "test"
          ttl          = 300
          ip_addresses = ["10.10.10.10"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Child Module - main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "zone" {
  for_each = var.dns_zone

  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = var.rsg_name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "link" {
  for_each = var.dns_zone

  name                  = each.value.vnet_link_name
  resource_group_name   = var.rsg_name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.zone[each.key].name
  virtual_network_id    = each.value.vnet_id
  registration_enabled  = each.value.registration_enabled
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "records" {
  for_each = { for a_record in var.dns_zone : a_record.name => a_record }

  name                = each.value.name
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.zone[each.key].name
  resource_group_name = var.rsg_name
  ttl                 = each.value.ttl
  records             = split(",", replace(each.value.ip_addresses, " ", ""))
}
```

**Child Module - variable.tf**

```
variable "dns_zone" {
  type = map(object({
    registration_enabled = bool
    vnet_link_name       = string
    vnet_id              = string
    a_record = list(object({
      name         = string,
      ttl          = number,
      ip_addresses = list(string)
    }))
  }))
```

**Child Module - output.tf**

```
output "zone" {
  value = azurerm_private_dns_zone.zone
}
output "records" {
  value = azurerm_private_dns_a_record.records
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` I get the following message:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ..\modules\vnet\main.tf line 176, in resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "records":
│  176:   for_each = { for a_record in var.dns_zone : a_record.name => a_record }
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "name".
```

My goal is to be able to create a dns_zone mapping that will create private DNS zones with each key. Within the key, I will be able to adjust specific settings and to also create a list of A records.

I've been working at this for awhile but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue in the for_each loop. If I comment out the Azure Private DNS A record resource only utilizing Private DNS zone and the Virtual Network link resources, it will display the Terraform Plan correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone reads this in the future and wonders how to resolve this, I found that I had to use the flatten function with nested for expressions. Here is the additional code. This went into the child module - main.tf file. Everything else remained the same. Once I ran a terraform plan, it successfully produced the plan information.

```
locals {
  dns_a_records = flatten([
    for dns_zone_key, zone in var.dns_zone : [
      for dns_record_key, record in zone.a_record : {
        dns_zone_key   = dns_zone_key
        dns_record_key = dns_record_key
        dns_zone_name  = azurerm_private_dns_zone.zone[dns_zone_key].name
        name           = record.name
        ttl            = record.ttl
        ip_addresses   = record.ip_addresses
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "records" {
  for_each = { for record in local.dns_a_records : "${record.dns_zone_key}.${record.dns_record_key}" => record }

  name                = each.value.name
  zone_name           = each.value.dns_zone_name
  resource_group_name = var.rsg_name
  ttl                 = each.value.ttl
  records             = each.value.ip_addresses
}
```